# Format Date from String - swift3

Tags: ios, date, swift3, date-format

HI I am trying to formate date from string (08-05-1988) I want to convert to date as given below, output also given below,

```
let dateString = "08-05-1988"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
let stringValue = String(describing: dateFromString)
```

**out put : Optional(1988-05-07 18:30:00 +0000)**

Then, I want to format the out put date from (1988-05-07 18:30:00 +0000) to other format as given below. But, when format the string to `Date` is `nil`

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss Z"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
let formatedDate:String = formatter.string(from: date!)
```

**Expected Output : 08-May-1988**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output `Optional(1988-05-07 18:30:00 +0000)` is the result of the `description` of a `Date` object. It's not related to any given string format.

To convert `08-05-1988` to `08-May-1988` you can simply use

```
let dateString = "08-05-1988"
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
let formatedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: dateFromString!)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let date = Date()

let format = DateFormatter()

format.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

let formatDate = format.string(from: date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `dateFormatter.date` on `dateString` instead of `dateFromString`.  Since  `"08-05-1988"` doesn't match the specified format of `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss Z"`, `dateFormatter.date` returns `nil`.